# How to remove an image's background and make it transparent?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

The code I use is this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/temp'
newData = []

for image in os.listdir(path):
    img = Image.open(path+'/'+image)
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    datas = img.getdata()

    for item in datas:
        if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            if item[0] > 150:
                newData.append((0, 0, 0, 255))
            else:
                newData.append(item)
                print(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save('C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/temp'+'/'+"open_science_logo_transparent.png", "PNG")
```

Original:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The result does not exactly make the background transparent.

How to improve the code and make the black background into transparent?

EDIT:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import shutil
path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/temp'
out_put = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/data science/cropped'
newData = []


for image in os.listdir(path):
    img = Image.open(path+'/'+image)
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    datas = img.getdata()
    
    for item in datas:
        if all(i == 0 for i in datas[0:3]):
            newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
        else:
            etcetcetc
img.putdata(newData)
img.save('C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/temp'+'/'+"open_science_logo_transparent.png", "PNG")
```

@NotActuallyErik

It shows an error

---

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

in  14 15 for item in datas: ---> 16 if all(i == 0 for i in datas[0:3]): 17 newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0)) 18 else:

TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'.

How to make it right?

Comment: I would use module `cv2` to work only with `numpy.array` without converting from/to `PIL`

Comment: it is trange: you run `for`-loop to read many images from folder but finally you save only one file.

Comment: What color is the background in the original image? If it is not a single color, what is it?

Comment: original image has black color background.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is telling PIL to remove replace every white pixel with a black one: `[255,255,255,0]` -> `[0,0,0,255]` which is why your black background remains while only the full-white spots get removed. You need to do the opposite to remove the background, i.e `[0,0,0,255]` -> `[0,0,0,0]`

this might work

```
for item in datas:
    if all(i == 0 for i in datas[0:3]):
        newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
    else:
        etcetcetc
```

Comment: you means `[0,0,0,255] -> [0,0,0,0]` instead of `[255,255,255,255] -> [0,0,0,0]`

Comment: Yes, sorry! You could even try:

     if all(item[i] < 50 for i in range(len(item[0:3]))):
        datas.append((0, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: @NotActuallyErik   It shows an error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-a3cc637e429c> in <module>
     14 
     15 for item in datas:
---> 16     if all(i == 0 for i in datas[0:3]):
     17         newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
     18     else:

TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'.


         How to make it right?

Comment: @GuanlinChen You want to check the first three elements in a list of four and apparently you cannot slice the list. Perhaps indexing the list of pixels could be useful somehow? Maybe range() and len() could help you?